# Get the unique total scores of students

Tags: javascript

I have a form on my school web application where teachers are able to add scores for students and at the end of each row, the total, which is the sum of input values is automatically calculated per student.

The problem is that it output the total of all the students instead of the total of individual students on all the rows even ones with no scores added.

How do I get the unique total value for each row?

[image: scores form]

Below is my code

```
<?php if($class_id >= 1 && $class_id <= 4 && $student['is_secmid'] == 1){?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/examgroup/entrymarks') ?>" id="assign_form1111">

    <input type="hidden" id="max_mark" value="<?php echo $subject_detail->max_marks; ?>">
 <?php

    if (isset($resultlist) && !empty($resultlist)) {

        ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="hidden" name="exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id" value="<?php echo $exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id; ?>">
 <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>C.A 1 (10.0)</th>
<th>C.A 2 (10.0)</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
<?php if (empty($resultlist)) {
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" class="text-danger text-center"><?php echo $this->lang->line('no_record_found'); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
} else {
foreach ($resultlist as $student) {
?>
<tr class="std_adm_<?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="prev_id[<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $student['exam_group_exam_result_id'] ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="exam_group_student_id[]" value="<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id'] ?>">
<td><?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?></td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $student['lastname'] . " " . $student['firstname']; ?></td>
<td> <input type="number" class="marksssss2 form-control" min="0" max="10" name="exam_group_student_ca1_<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $student['exam_group_exam_result_get_ca1']; ?>" step="any"></td>

<td> <input type="number" class="marksssss3 form-control" min="0" max="10" name="exam_group_student_ca2_<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $student['exam_group_exam_result_get_ca2']; ?>" step="any"></td>

<td> <output class="result"></output></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<?php if ($this->rbac->hasPrivilege('exam_marks', 'can_edit')) { ?>

  <button type="submit" class="allot-fees btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Please Wait.."><?php echo $this->lang->line('save'); ?>

    </button>

    <?php } ?>

  </div>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

```js
<script>
const $inputs = $('input[type="number"]')

$inputs.change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var parent = $(this).closest('.row');
  parent.find('input[type="number"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });
  parent.find('.result').html(total);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There is no element with a class of `row` in your code.

Comment: there is, i just didn't show that part. The code will be too much

Comment: It is very difficult for us to help you if we cannot reproduce the issue. You should provide enough code to show the error. If there is too much code, you need to make a **minimal** example.

Comment: Please could youy take a look at it agin? I've added the full code

Comment: <tr class="std_adm_<?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?>"> can you list here all classes used in HTML on this TR? @mar

Comment: @ahmedmoeed, they are marksssss2 and marksssss3

Comment: add class row here 
<tr class="std_adm_<?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?>">

Comment: <tr class="row std_adm_<?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?>">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251185/discussion-between-ahmed-moeed-and-mary4bills).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed class row on `<tr>` and you are trying to find it on `closest` div from javascript, and you are getting this `(<div class="row">)`, it have all the `(<input type="number")`.

you forget to add class to `TR`. Add class row on `<tr>` so you can get all `(<input type="number")` inside the tr.

because of not added class on `TR` you are facing issue that all total have same numbers.